# org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll returns "g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface “”"

Tags: python, linux, dbus

I am writing a python script for search .deb packages on USB-Flash and faced the following problem: when calling the method `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll("")` I get

```py
g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface “”
```

Replacing the method argument with any of the existing interfaces gives the same result, only the name of the entered interface is written instead of "". Passing the device as an argument also doesn't help.

When running the same method via d-feet, the result is the same.

A fragment of the script code:

```
_bus = dbus.SystemBus()
_proxy = _bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2','/org/freedesktop/UDisks2')
_iface = dbus.Interface(_proxy, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')

for _dev in _iface.GetManagedObjects():
    _dev_obj = _bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2', _dev)
    _dev_prop = dbus.Interface(_dev_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
    print(_dev_prop.GetAll('org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'))
```

[Screenshot from d-feet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kKYj.png)

What could be the matter?

Edit1:

Figured it out. You must pass the org interface.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive. In this case, we get the following result:

```
{'CanPowerOff': True,
 'Configuration': {},
 'ConnectionBus': 'usb',
 'Ejectable': True,
 'Id': 'Kingston-DataTraveler-3.0-D067E5161936F1C156119E3E',
 'Media': 'thumb',
 'MediaAvailable': True,
 'MediaChangeDetected': True,
 'MediaCompatibility': ['thumb'],
 'MediaRemovable': False,
 'Model': 'DataTraveler 3.0',
 'Optical': False,
 'OpticalBlank': False,
 'OpticalNumAudioTracks': 0,
 'OpticalNumDataTracks': 0,
 'OpticalNumSessions': 0,
 'OpticalNumTracks': 0,
 'Removable': True,
 'Revision': '0001',
 'RotationRate': -1,
 'Seat': 'seat0',
 'Serial': 'D067E5161936F1C156119E3E',
 'SiblingId': '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0',
 'Size': 7736072192,
 'SortKey': '01hotplug/1661266466752717',
 'TimeDetected': 1661266466752717,
 'TimeMediaDetected': 1661266466752717,
 'Vendor': 'Kingston',
 'WWN': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.UDisks2 --object-path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2` results:

```
node /org/freedesktop/UDisks2 {
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties {
    methods:
      Get(in  s interface_name,
          in  s property_name,
          out v value);
      GetAll(in  s interface_name,
             out a{sv} properties);
      Set(in  s interface_name,
          in  s property_name,
          in  v value);
    signals:
      PropertiesChanged(s interface_name,
                        a{sv} changed_properties,
                        as invalidated_properties);
    properties:
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable {
    methods:
      Introspect(out s xml_data);
    signals:
    properties:
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer {
    methods:
      Ping();
      GetMachineId(out s machine_uuid);
    signals:
    properties:
  };
  interface org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager {
    methods:
      GetManagedObjects(out a{oa{sa{sv}}} object_paths_interfaces_and_properties);
    signals:
      InterfacesAdded(o object_path,
                      a{sa{sv}} interfaces_and_properties);
      InterfacesRemoved(o object_path,
                        as interfaces);
    properties:
  };
  node Manager {
  };
  node drives {
  };
  node block_devices {
  };
};
```

According to [D-Bus Specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties):

> An empty string may be provided for the interface name; in this case, if there are multiple properties on an object with the same name, the results are undefined (picking one by according to an arbitrary deterministic rule, or returning an error, are the reasonable possibilities).

My guess you are facing one of these **undefined results**.

But my question is, why do you need to call this method? according to the introspection result the requested path doesn't contain any properties!

Comment: Contains. Here is the output of the method:

I found which interface needs to be passed as an argument: org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive. It is as strange as possible to pass an interface related to UDisks2, despite the fact that I pass the org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties interface to the Interface() method. Maybe I just don't understand something...

In any case, I'm editing the question by adding an answer to it. I hope it will help someone in the future